# Use jQuery to force two checkboxes mirror each other's state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form, event-handling

**RESTRICTION: jQuery 1.6.4 only, no other library, or version can be used.**

My goal is to use jQuery to allow two input checkboxes behave the same.

For example: If 1st checkbox is checked, 2nd will be checked. If 1st is unchecked, 2nd will be unchecked. And vise versa. When either of the checkbox is checked, I will add a class to the HTML `body` tag, if it's unchecked, remove the class to the `body` tag.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='true' id='1'/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='true' id='2'/>
</body>
```

I can't modify the input tags, that means I can't give it a class name. I can only use what is there. Meantime, I try to make as less jQuery calls as possible, in order to increase performance. I try to write as less code as possible, so I came up this piece of code:

jQuery:

```
$('input:checkbox').live('change', function () {
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
  if ($('input:checkbox').is(":checked")) {
    $('body').addClass('checked');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('checked');
  }
});
```

The code works, but I am not happy with it. I think it can be improved. I especially do not like the part `$('input:checkbox'),` I am concerned about the speed when querying the DOM with `$('input:checkbox')`. How can I improve? Any other problems?

Comment: `var checkboxes = $(…)` and use that instead of querying every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As said in other answer, cache the DOM elements references so you don't have to *dive* into DOM to get the elements again and again on each check/uncheck of the checkboxes.
2. Use `$(document.body)` to refer to `<body>` element, this is *slight* faster. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12307155/2025923).
3. Use a common class on all the interested checkboxes. `$('input:checkbox')` is a general selector and it'll select all the checkboxes on the page.
4. You can use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) with second param which can be used to decide whether to add or remove class from elements. If the second param is `true` class is added and if it is `false` class is removed.
5. As the checkboxes are by default checked, add the class on the `<body>` by default.
6. `this.checked` is faster than `$(this).is(':checked')`. It just checks the property on the current elements. Whereas in jQuery, it has to call the `is()` function and check if the passed argument status on the element.
7. IF POSSIBLE, update the jQuery version to latest one. It has many performance improvements and bug-fixes.

**Live Demo:**

```js
// Cache the elements
var $myCheckbox = $('.myCheckbox'),
  $body = $(document.body);1

// On change of the checked state of checkbox
$myCheckbox.live('change', function() {
  // Update the checked property of all other checkboxes
  $myCheckbox.prop('checked', this.checked);

  // Add/Remove the class on body
  $body.toggleClass('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```css
/* For DEMO purpose */
body.checked {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="checked">
  <input type="checkbox" checked='true' class="myCheckbox" id='1' />
  <input type="checkbox" checked='true' class="myCheckbox" id='2' />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Don't run selectors every time.
const checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');
const body = $('body');

checkboxes.live('change', function () {
  // Remember the state and update all checkboxes.
  const checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  checkboxes.prop('checked', checked);

  // Toggle class.
  if (checked)
    body.addClass('checked');
  else
    body.removeClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: jQuery has `toggleClass` method

Comment: @wOxxOm it does, but it is not appropriate here, since we need to set it to checkbox value, not opposite of previous value.

Comment: A common misunderstanding. See the other answer. The method accepts a second parameter.

Comment: @wOxxOm since it is so common to misunderstand this method, why use it in confusing context?

Comment: It's common because people don't read documentation thoroughly, not because it's confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: I do agree though that setClassState or something would be more obvious.